# Finding a file within recursive directory of zip files

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed, grep

I have an entire directory structure with zip files. I would like to:

1. Traverse the entire directory structure recursively grabbing all the zip files
2. I would like to find a specific file "*myLostFile.ext" within one of these zip files.

**What I have tried**
1. I know that I can list files recursively pretty easily:

```
find myLostfile -type f
```

2. I know that I can list files inside zip archives:

```
unzip -ls myfilename.zip
```

**How do I find a specific file within a directory structure of zip files?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can omit using find for single-level (or recursive in bash 4 with `globstar`) searches of `.zip` files using a `for` loop approach:

```
for i in *.zip; do grep -iq "mylostfile" < <( unzip -l $i ) && echo $i; done
```

for recursive searching in bash 4:

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.zip; do grep -iq "mylostfile" < <( unzip -l $i ) && echo $i; done
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `xargs` to process the output of find or you can do something like the following:

```
find . -type f -name '*zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -l "{}" | grep -q myLostfile' \; -print
```

which will start searching in `.` for files that match `*zip` then will run `unzip -ls` on each and search for your filename.  If that filename is found it will print the name of the zip file that matched it.

Comment: **Note:** there is no option `s` to `unzip` on linux. Otherwise, the command works.

Comment: Usage: unzip [-Z] [-opts[modifiers]] file[.zip] [list] [-x xlist] [-d exdir]
  Default action is to extract files in list, except those in xlist, to exdir;
  file[.zip] may be a wildcard.  -Z => ZipInfo mode ("unzip -Z" for usage).

Comment: As David had noted, there should not be an `s` in my unzip command, I'm editing now to remove that